# How can I restage moved files that were reset in git?

Tags: git

I moved a bunch of files around using `git mv`. But then I committed a change to a file and the commit included all of the moved files. Then I `git reset` to the previous commit, and now all of the files I had staged as moved, are now marked as deleted and untracked.

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    file1
    deleted:    file2

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    test/file1
    test/file2
```

Is there a way to mark them all as moved again? I would rather have a better looking commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git add --all
```

Will will mark files as removed/added.

Answer (score 0):

The `git reset` command did unstage all the changes you made in the commit (a detailed [explanation](http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html) on `reset` command). In your case it was better to use `git reset --soft`, which keeps staged changes. 
But the good news is - you can still actually use it! Just do a HARD reset to the last commit you made. Its hash code can by found using `git reflog`, you will see something like that:

[image]

Then do:

```
git reset --hard 4cc2cbe (instead of 4cc2cbe use hash code of the commit in which you moved the files)
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Comment: Hmm, this might have worked if I didn't make any more commits, but I did and it kinda reverted things in a strange way. I made a backup so no worries. And I was able to get the desired behavior by running `git add --all`